# Showing data like a tree in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I have a table as listed below

```
ID   Name   Parent
1     A       0
2     B       1
3     c       1
4     D       2
5     E       2
6     F       0
..    ..      ..
```

What I need is to show it like

```
 - A
    -B
     - D
     - E 
    -C

 - F
```

I am making `datatables` in c# like

I am getting the data with `jquery-ajax` and preparing the html from a `web method`, but I don't want to use any plugin for making the treeview.

Select The records in dtParent where Parent = 0

After this I am trying to filter the records for child entries.

I believe this can be easily done with the recursion but I am not able to find the correct logic.

The code I tried (dtGoals is table where I have all the records and in dtData I am getting only Parents)

```
dtData = dtGoals;
dtData.DefaultView.RowFilter = "ID = " + dtGoals.Rows[goalCount]["GoalId"].ToString();
dtData.AcceptChanges();
dtData = dtData.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

After RowFilter Parent records are in `dtData`. Make the tree node with first record (ID = 1). Now I don't know how to proceed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.jstree.com/

Comment: Minor point, but your demo tree doesn't match the data. `D` and `E` should be under `B` and not `C`

Comment: Put you code also so that some one don't have write it from screech

Comment: @freefaller the demo updated

Comment: @Shekhar I did only filtering for parent record that's why not showing the code here BUT added now :)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not a code writing service. And I don't react to "urgent" requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Item
{
    public Item()
    {
        Children = new List<Item>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Children { get; set; } 
}

public class TreeBuilder
{
    public TreeBuilder(IEnumerable<Item> items)
    {
        _items = new HashSet<Item>(items);
        TreeRootItems = new List<Item>();
        TreeRootItems.AddRange(_items.Where(x => x.ParentId == 0));
        BuildTree(TreeRootItems);
    }

    private readonly HashSet<Item> _items;
    public List<Item> TreeRootItems { get; private set; }


    public void BuildTree(List<Item> result)
    {
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            item.Children.AddRange(_items.Where(x => x.ParentId == item.Id));
            BuildTree(item.Children);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am interested in the solution based on simple asp.net DataTables, can you provide the same.

Comment: give some explanations also

Answer (score 0):

a jQuery solution :

http://jsfiddle.net/Pascalz/HqDBX/

HTML :

```
<div id="0">
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
var datas = [
    {ID:1,Name:"A",Parent:0},
    {ID:2,Name:"B",Parent:1},
    {ID:3,Name:"C",Parent:1},
    {ID:4,Name:"D",Parent:2},
    {ID:5,Name:"E",Parent:2},
    {ID:6,Name:"F",Parent:0}
];

$.each(datas, function (index, item) {
   $('#' + String(item.Parent)).append($('<div class=\'t\' id=\'' + item.ID + '\'>' + item.Name + '</div>'));
});
```

CSS:

```
div {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
div.t:before{content: "- "}
```

Comment: :) but no jquery solution is required. I am interested in the solution based on simple asp.net DataTables, can you provide the same

Comment: ha... you have jquery tagged your question.

Comment: yes, but that was related to question that what I am using an jquery-ajax function for dealing with server side code. But the web-method is responsible for making the tree structure :)